# Make value from every second row appear in new 3rd column

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets assume my data looks like this :
Every second row represents old (previous value) in a table that holds historical data.

**table 1 :**

```
id     value
------------
1       a
1       b
2       c
2       d
3       a
3       b
```

and i want to get value of every second row to appear in new 3rd column like this :

**table 2:**

```
id    new_value    old_value
------------------------
1       a          b
2       c          d
3       a          b
```

EDIT:
For clarity ill post the skeleton of query thats producing data i want to transform (so its clear i am already using `WITH` so cant use additional one due to oracle not yet allowing nesting of `WITH` elements) :

**skeleton code that produces data in table 1** :

```
with candidates as 
(
        --select list of candidates
)
SELECT * FROM
(
  (
        --select new values
  MINUS
        --select old values
  )
UNION
  (
        --select old values
  MINUS
        --select new values
  )
)
ORDER BY id;
```

The goal is to finally get only a list of ids that changed with their old and new values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no first or second row, unless a column explicitly specifies the ordering.

Comment: Oracle and other DBMS doesn't order its records. So how could we **defined** which is **first** row, which is **second** of each group by id?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach using the id as a group by and order in which values are give, as this data is already a result of rather complex query, but im controling the order of those values, and every second value is indeed second.

Comment: Always two rows per id, never more or less?

Comment: @jarlh yes, always only 2 rows per id

Comment: You don't need to nest CTEs, you can define several in a row and one CTE can refer back to all those already defined, al, in one WITH clause. Skim through answers on this site, you will see many examples.

Comment: @mathguy can you use my skeleton code and show me what you think, as this code as whole returnd data in table 1, so i dont see how can i refer to this as whole, as i have no use refering to my candidates CTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible that overall query can be written in a much simpler way. Just join intermediary results with old and new values together on `id` to put them in two different columns instead of unioning them into the same column.

```
WITH
candidates
AS
(
    --select list of candidates
)
,CTE_NewValues
AS
(
    --select new values
    select id, value AS new_value
    FROM candidates
    WHERE ...
    -- assumes id is unique, one row per id
)
,CTE_OldValues
AS
(
    --select old values
    select id, value AS old_value
    FROM candidates
    WHERE ...
    -- assumes id is unique, one row per id
)
SELECT
    CTE_NewValues.id
    ,CTE_NewValues.new_value
    ,CTE_OldValues.old_value
FROM
    CTE_NewValues
    INNER JOIN CTE_OldValues ON CTE_NewValues.id = CTE_OldValues.id
WHERE
    CTE_NewValues.new_value <> CTE_OldValues.old_value
ORDER BY
    CTE_NewValues.id;
```

---

If we stick to the skeleton of the query in the question, there are also many ways to do it. Self-join is likely to be less efficient than using analytic functions, like `ROW_NUMBER` and `LEAD`.

Sorting just by `id` is not enough to unambiguously define which value is new or old. You need to have some extra column to resolve it.

You don't "nest" `WITH` (common-table expressions), you "chain" them. Something like the following. As you do that, make sure to add the `sort_order` column to be able to distinguish old and new values, if you don't have a similar column already.

```
WITH
candidates 
AS
(
    --select list of candidates
)
,CTE_YourQuery
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        (
        --select new values
        select 1 AS sort_order, id, value
        MINUS
        --select old values
        select 1 AS sort_order, id, value
        )
    UNION ALL
        (
        --select old values
        select 2 AS sort_order, id, value
        MINUS
        --select new values
        select 2 AS sort_order, id, value
        )
    )
)
,CTE_RowNumber
AS
(
    SELECT
        id
        ,value AS new_value
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY sort_order) AS rn
        ,LEAD(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY sort_order) AS old_value
    FROM CTE_YourQuery
)
SELECT
    id
    ,new_value
    ,old_value
FROM CTE_RowNumber
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: The second example you made, might do the trick! Going to try this out.
First example is not gonna work for me because the row number will cause me to detect those records as changed in my union of inverted minuses.

Comment: This indeed led me to the solution, even tho i didnt create sort fields in CTE_YourQuery. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 3):

Use CTE

```
;WITH CTE AS(

   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) RN
   FROM TableName
)   
SELECT ID,
       MIN(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN [value] END) NewValue,
       MIN(CASE WHEN RN=2 THEN [value] END) OldValue
FROM CTE    
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Ordering by the same column that is used to `PARTITION` is correct syntax, but doesn't make much sense. New and Old values may be swapped randomly in the result. Of course, in some cases it is acceptable, but quite often it is not.

Comment: oracle sadly still doesnt support nesting of `with` and my query that outputs this data uses `with` already, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: @MladenOršolić not sure about what you saying but I suggest visit this link https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause :)

Comment: @JaydipJ Its only possible to have 1 with within query, and i already use one to produce data i want to transform. Ill edit my post to include th skeleton of my query for clarity.

Comment: Yes that make sense

Comment: `[value]` is an invalid identifier in SQL and Oracle

Comment: @MladenOršolić: you don't need to "nest" CTEs - just put one after the other: `with cte_1 as (..), cte_2 as (..), cte_3 as (...) select ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, i anonimized my data here on SO, actual field names are different.

Comment: @MladenOršolić how is that important for the question about "nesting" CTEs?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name man im just replying to your comment :  
[value] is an invalid identifier in SQL and Oracle – a_horse_with_no_name 8 mins ago

Comment: @MladenOršolić: yes because `[` is invalid in an SQL identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is some other column which defines the "order" in which the new and old value appears, you can do this:

```
select t1.id, t1.value as old_value, t2.value as new_value
from the_table t1
  join the_table t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.sort_order < t2.sort_order
```

But you **have** to have some column that distinguishes the row that is considered "old" from the one that is considered "new".